# Do you like hats?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* because we all love hats, right? right?

But to get this awesome hat promotion we have to **opt in**. That means acting on this meta post, whether that's voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments and/or just directing positive energy this direction.

I think this is a good chance at a bit of harmless fun, that could potentially help keep site traffic up through the northern hemisphere winter (when traffic usually dies down a bit for us).

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

Again, please let us know what you think as this is your site not ours.

(Majority of content blatantly stolen from [waxeagle](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/wax-eagle)'s [post on meta.christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats).)

**UPDATE: I sent off the email, making it official. We will be on the hat plan.**

Comment: Blatant theft? I approve this! :P No, actually, **waxeagle** has a fine way with words. :)

Comment: Only if all the hats are safe biking with!

Comment: @Informaficker: 3/5ths of the hats I posted in the answer fit under a bicycle helmet quite nicely.

Answer (score 6):

## **Yay Hats!**

It's just a bit of harmless fun. If somebody doesn't like it, they can just click the `I hate hats` button, and the hats will all go away.

[image: freiheit in a top hat with a ridiculous mustache]
[image: freiheit in a cycling cap. black with white racing stripe]
[image: freiheit in a patchwork wool flat cap.]
[image: freiheit in a brown wool cycling cap with ear flaps up]
[image: freiheit with belgian-style ear flaps down]
[image: freiheit in a cycling cap. Grey wool with a black racing stripe]

See. None of those hats hurt anybody. The ear flaps were a bit warm for in the office, though.

Comment: That first one is amazing.

Comment: @Aarthi: I was at a local steampunk event

Comment: It just keeps getting better.

Comment: This is the best "hats or no hats?" post on any meta anywhere.

Comment: MOAR HATS!!!!!!

Comment: nice 'tache there @freiheit! Moar hats are always good!